# Allow user to cancel Login attempt and retry manually without destroying Observables

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Say I have a Login button that's bound to an observer in my VM.

When the user taps the button it triggers an async API call. The VC listens for the results of the call on an Observable exposed by the VM.

I show a Cancel button, in case the async activity gets stuck or the user realizes they typed their password wrong and want to try again. If the user cancels I'd like to effectively cancel or ignore events emitted as a result of the first tap, and allow the user to tap Login again when they're ready.

setup is something like this:

```swift
class SimpleVM {

  struct Output {
    let loginResponse: Observable<LoginResponse>
  }
  struct Input {
    let loginDidTap: AnyObserver<Void>
    let cancelDidTap: AnyObserver<Void>
  }

  let output: Output
  let input: Input

  private let loginSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
  private let cancelSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

  init() {
    let response = loginSubject
      .flatMapLatest { _ in
        loginService.login(username, password)
      }

    cancelSubject
      .flatMapLatest { _ in 
         // do something here?
    }

    input = Input(loginDidTap: loginSubject.asObserver(), cancelDidTap: cancelSubject.asObserver())
    output = Output(loginResponse: response)
  }
}

class SimpleVC: UIViewController {
  var loginButton: UIButton!
  var cancelButton: UIButton!
  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  func bind(vm: SimpleVM) {
    loginButton.rx.tap
      .bind(to: vm.input.loginDidTap)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    cancelButton.rx.tap
      .bind(to: vm.input.cancelDidTap)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    vm.output.loginResponse
      .subscribe(onNext: { response in
        print("Got token \(response.info.token)")
      }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}
```

How do I handle the cancel button tap such that it effectively "resets" things so the user can attempt to login again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
enum Action {
    case start
    case stop
}

let loginResult = Observable.merge(loginDidTap.map { Action.start }, cancelDidTap.map { Action.stop })
    .flatMapLatest { action in 
        switch action {
            case .start:
                loginService.login(username, password)
            case .stop:
                Observable.empty()
        }
    }
```